# Any JavaScript editor to display output without HTML or CSS?

Tags: javascript

Is there any way I can view JavaScript outputs without having any HTML or CSS.
Any IDE/Editor, or Online/Offline Tool/Website?

Like, if I just type `console.log("Hello")` without any HTML or CSS file, it should show me `Hello`.

Thanks :)

Comment: Developer Console of your browser.

Comment: you can also install nodejs and use command line to run it.

Comment: Ya, `console.log()` works there but `return` displays error. I was hoping full functionality. @PM77-1

Comment: @MARUFSARKER do you mean you get an error when you try to enter a return statement outside of a method? When I enter `function foo() {return "bar"}; foo()` my console prints `"bar"` no problem.

Comment: @Sam, oh yes. Thank you. I was trying `return` directly without any function/method.

Answer (score 2):

how about repl.it, perhaps something like this:

http://repl.it/languages/JavaScript